# Apache base URL for subdirectory?

Tags: apache

I've got my site in `htdocs/mysite` which I'll be using to test/develop my website locally. Problem is, now all my URLs in my HTML/CSS need to begin with `mysite` whereas they won't on the product environment. What's the best way around this? Is there something I can add to `httpd.conf` to tell it anything in `mysite` should be relative to `mysite`? I'm still an apache noob, so please by detailed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just omit the preceding slash on each file reference? i.e.,

```
.myClass {
    background-image: url(images/stuff.png);
}
```

I'm guessing you want something more substantial. Use an .htaccess file in the /mysite directory. All the info you need is here: [RewriteBase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase)

Comment: No, can't omit it. CSS might be included from a subdirectory.

Comment: The URL is relative to the CSS file's path, presuming your CSS file is external to the HTML document.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't see why simply using relative paths doesn't completely solve this issue. Use 'background-image: url(../images/stuff.png);' and '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />'

Comment: I agree. I verified the path worked fine as long as your relative path is correct in relation to the location of the CDs file.

Comment: that was supposed to be "css file". Thanks, iPhone!